# web2py Login with username or email

Tags: email, authentication, web2py

I'm using web2py and I currently have a login form that takes an email address and password. I need to be able to accept a username or email address to login. I found a solution here:
http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1642/login-with-username-and-email

and I included the code there, but when I enter a username instead of email, it gives the error Invalid Email.

I think if I knew where it was doing that email check, I might be able to fix it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe little late for the answer, but I had the same problem and I found a workaround:

First I checked if the input is a valid email (email flow), if so, proceed (the happy path). When the input is a username I do search in the database for the user associated with that username and get its email. After that, I do replace the email in *vars* and *post_vars*.

For example:

```python
def user():

```
if 'login' in request.args:
    if request.env.method=='POST':
        if request.vars.email and not IS_EMAIL()(request.vars.email)[1]:
            try:
                email = db(db.auth_user.username==request.vars.email).select(db.auth_user.email).first().as_dict()['email']
                request.post_vars.email = request.vars.email = email
            except:
                pass
```

```